# Way to parameterise sparse multi diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an NxN matrix S that looks like this: $$ S^{-1} = K^{-1} + \Lambda $$

where N is a multiple of 3, both K and S are positive definite matrices, and Lambda is
$$
\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}
x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0\\
0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0\\
0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x\\
x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0\\
0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0\\
0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x\\
x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0\\
0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0\\
0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x &0 &0 &x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where x denote non-zero entries, note that these can be different. 
To ensure positive definiteness, to parameterise/optimise S, we often use the Cholesky decomposition of S, S = R'R. However, doing things like this involves N*(N+1)/2 parameters.

As S has the form above, and K is known, an alternative is to parameterise \Lambda as it has only 3*N non-zero elements. However, I found it tricky to ensure S is positive definite, anyone deal with this before? Diagonal \Lambda is easy, but multi-diagonal \Lambda ??

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear how $\Lambda$ is defined for a generic $n$. What are its nonzero diagonals? Is it [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)?

Comment: I should have been clearer, \Lambda is a 3k*3k matrix, where it has non zero elements along the main diagonal, +k/-k-th diagonals, and 2k/-2k-th diagonals. S and K are covariance matrices, hence \Lambda needs to be symmetric, but I'm not sure what the conditions on non-zero elements of \Lambda are.

And it is not circulant.